# Setting Pandas index to be a given DateTimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to pull some daily data, and some data is missing.  I would like to fill with something (havent decided on 0's, nans or average filling).  I can get a df1 that has an index of the form:

```
print(df1.columns)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
               '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Now I try to pull down some df2, that is missing, lets say '2020-01-08'. Is there a way I can assert that `df2.index = df1.index`, with there being a column for the missing date, but the data (probably just NaNs that can be ffilled).

Comment: short answer to ur question - yes. better is to share some data on what u r trying to achieve, where u got stuck and ur expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `reindex`

```
df2.reindex(df1.index)
```